# Handing and analyze data after multiple imputation in R mice

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

For example, I have a dataset (original_data) including five varibales: V1, V2, V3, sex, Outcome. some values of V1, V2, V3 are missing.

```
set.seed(123456)
original_data <- data.table(
    V1 = rnorm(20),
    V2 = rnorm(20),
    V3 = rnorm(20),
    sex = sample(c("M", "W"), 20, replace = TRUE),
    Outcome = rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
)
original_data$V1[sample(20, 2)] <- NA
original_data$V2[sample(20, 5)] <- NA
original_data$V3[sample(20, 7)] <- NA
original_data
```

I imputed the dataset using mice package in R. Now, I have an imputed dataset named "imp_data".(Please ignose the Warning message)

```
imp_data <- mice::mice(original_data, m = 5)
```

1. I want to creat a new variable "Vsum", which is the sum of V1, V2, V3. In a unimputed dataset, I can creat it easily by Vsum <- V1 + V2 + V3, how could I creat it in an imputed dataset.

```
original_data$Vsum <- original_data$V1 + original_data$V2 + original_data$V3 
# in unimputed dataset
```

2. I want to calaculate the odds ratio (Outcome ~ V1). I can do it using with(imp_data, glm(Outcome ~ V1,family = binomial(link = 'logit'))), How could I calaculate the sex-specific odds ratio?

```
glm(Outcome ~ V1,family = binomial(link = 'logit'),data = original_data[sex == "W"]) 
# in unimputed dataset
```

Comment: could we have  a [mcve] please?

Comment: I have added a example. I don't know the rules about this. Is that example accepteable?